# loop over querySelector, undefined inside loop

Tags: javascript

I`m trying to perform loop below:

```
function lockSubmits(selector,value){

   var submitInputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
       for(var jk = 0; jk<=submitInputs.length; jk++){
         submitInputs[jk].disabled = value;
       }

}
```

when submitInputs[jk].disabled = value; is going to happen console throw submitInputs[jk] is undefined why?? The 'selector' is correct and it matches items when Im trying to match it outside the function

Comment: `jk<=submitInputs.length;` Off-by-one error

Comment: The highest index in the list is `submitInputs.length - 1`, not `submitInputs.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works, but it fails with last item which doesn't exist.
You should iterate only `length` amount of times. You are off by 1.

```
 function lockSubmits(selector,value){

   var submitInputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
       for(var jk = 0; jk < submitInputs.length; jk++){
         submitInputs[jk].disabled = value;
       }

}
```